# AS3 Detecting Borders in Bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing

I need a library which, fed with a bitmap, returns me an array of rectangles with coordinates and dimensions of the different areas found in the image.

I'll give a graphic example:

From this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Or from this:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Is there such a library?

If I want to write one on my own where can I start to inform myself about it?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the best you'll find are [image filters](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/imageprocessing-library/), and color conversion methods, but not the kind of [complicated edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) you're looking for.

Of course, your query supersedes the canny edge detection, and is focused on image boundaries, but I've found no material on that even beyond AS3.

Comment: unfortunately me neither =\